# Prestashop 1.7.5 module - Update SQL custom table

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add a new module to my shop to manage the sql table's values that I made. I can't find a proper guide that show me how to do that because all the forms have values contained in ps_configuration and not within a custom table.
How can I show those values in my form and get to update them?

Thank you if you'll take the time to answer that ^^

So, my form fields are still blank and they don't update my table when I submit.

I added this to "_construct" function:

```
public function __construct() {
$this->id_sell = $id_sell;
$this->country = $country;
$this->p_cod = $p_cod;
```

and this to "getContent"

```
public function getContent() {

$sqlV = 'SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mytable` WHERE id_sell = 1';
    if ($row = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sqlV))

    $country = $row[country];
    $p_cod = $row[p_cod];
```

and last this on "getConfigFormValues":

```
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
       return array(
        'country' => Tools::getValue('country'),
        'p_cod' => Tools::getValue('p_cod'),
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried again and again, can't obtain to link my array with the field values :(

Answer (score 0):

So, now I know that a need a class ObjectModel {}, too. Working on it.. and hoping for the best :D